# Как обновить NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

[`npm`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPM) можно обновить командой:

```
npm update npm -g
```

Однако, как обновить саму ноду, я не знаю.

<sup>[Перевод вопроса "How do I update Node.js?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/how-do-i-update-node-js)</sup>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191459/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Использовать Bash-скрипт для управления/переключения нодой: [**`nvm`**](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).
[Версия для `Windows`](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

Особый смак в переключениях активной версии ноды, например:

```
nvm list
 * 4.6.1
   0.12.0

node -v
   v4.6.1

nvm use 0.12.0
   Now using node v0.12.0

node -v
   v0.12.0
```

---

Если хочется попроще, то предлагаю использовать следующий алгоритм:

1. Очистить кэш `npm`:

   ```
   npm cache clean -f
   ```
2. Установить менеджер версий NodeJS: [**`n`**](https://github.com/tj/n):

   ```
   npm install -g n
   ```
3. Установить версию ноды:

   1. Стабильная версия:

      ```
      n stable
      ```
   2. Последняя версия:

      ```
      n latest
      ```
   3. Установка определённой версии:

      ```
      n 0.8.14
      ```
   4. Удаление определённой версии:

      ```
      n rm 0.8.14
      ```

      Или:

      ```
      n - 0.8.14
      ```

---

Для OS X можно использовать менеджер пакетов [`Homebrew`](https://brew.sh/index_ru.html):

```
$ brew upgrade node
```

Comment: Ответ выполняет поставленную задачу, но лучше использовать `nvm`, который специально для этого и был создан + он дает возможность очень просто переключаться между версиями

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, пожалуй да, можно и про него добавить. Сейчас обновлю.

Answer (score 8):

Когда мне на CentOs 7 требовалось обновить версию NodeJs(там по-моему изначально 6-ая стоит), поскольку в частности не устанавливался Puppeteer я обновлялся до 10-ой версии по этой статье http://blog.ivru.net/?id=221

Если коротко там написано, что NodeJs стандартной версии на CentOs 7 устанавливается выполнением команды: yum install nodejs

При этом если Вам нужна более свежая версия NodeJs чем стандартная, Вы можете перед установкой выполнить команду curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo bash - в данном примере команды для установки будет выбрана 10-ая версия, Вы перед нажатием Enter можете отредактировать версию на нужную Вам.

Более подробно по установке читайте по ссылке, так же в этой же статье Вы сможете найти файлы необходимых репозиториев(по умолчанию или необходимых для установки) в случаи если Ваши файлы повреждены и попытка установки заканчивается ошибкой.

Comment: Извините, сейчас добавлю описание.

Comment: Исправил ответ, добавил описание того что написано в статье как Вы и рекомендовали.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы обновить `nodejs`, на windows, можно скачать файл .msi и установить его. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы обновить npm на windows,нужно вызвать powrshell от администратора и прописать следующее

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser -Force
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade
```

Comment: npm-windows-upgrade --npm-version latest

Answer (score 1):

Способ, который подходит для любой ОС (включая Windows, Mac и Linux)

---

Просто зайдите на официальный сайт [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/ru/) ([nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/ru/)), скачайте установщик и запустите.

Программа установки позаботится обо всём, и уже после нескольких кликов по кнопке «Далее» вы станете счастливым обладателем Node.js на своём компьютере. С 2020 года именно этот способ обновления NodeJS является рекомендуемым. Это самое простое и проверенное временем решение.

[image: Скачать NodeJS для Windows, кнопки]

[image: Скачать исходный код Node.js или готовый установщик для Win/Mac, кнопки]

---

**Советы от профессионалов**

- Установка NodeJS включает в себя NPM (менеджер пакетов Node).
- Чтобы проверить версию NPM, используйте команду `npm version` или `node --version`.
- Если вы предпочитаете CLI, для обновления NPM используйте `npm install -g npm`, а затем `npm install -g node`.

  - Дополнительные сведения см. в документации по команде [`install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install?v=true).
- Следите за блогом [NodeJS — Vulnerabilities](https://nodejs.org/ru/blog/vulnerability/), чтобы не пропустить важные исправления для брешей в безопасности. Поддерживайте свой NodeJS в актуальном состоянии.
- Операционные системы, поддерживаемые Node.js:

  - [Windows](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), [Linux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux), [MacOS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS), [IBM AIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_AIX).
  - Для пользователей [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) вот официальный [образ Node.js](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/).

---

Это [перевод моего ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32756898/1429387).